# In JQuery Mobile, data-mini doesn't work in collapsible set

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am a newbie programmer in JQuery mobile and I'm trying to do a simple collapsible set that can be filtered. The filter looks good, but I can't make data-mini to work. The desired effect is to have the mini version of the collapsible set.

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-mini="true" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterable-input">         

      <div data-role="collapsible" data-filtertext="section1">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <p>I'm the collapsibleset content for section 1. My content is initially visible.</p>
      </div>

      <div data-role="collapsible" data-filtertext="section2">
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <p>I'm the collapsibleset content for section 2.</p>
      </div>

</div>
```

Here is the JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g48uns3g/

Thanks in advance,
Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample to test what a mini vs a normal collapsible-set looks like.  My HTML code can be found towards the bottom but a jsFiddle can be found here:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/Lvvr0yLk/)

When I compare this (visually) to your sample, I appear to see that your sample is indeed working and is "mini" it is just that unless you compare mini vs non-mini side by side, it is hard to tell.

```
<div class="ui-content">
     <h4>Normal</h4>
    <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-mini="false">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>I'm a normal collapsible</h3>
            <p>This is good for tight spaces.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>I'm another normal</h3>
            <p>Here's some collapsible content.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Last one</h3>
            <p>Final bit of collapsible content.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Mini</h4>
    <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-mini="true">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>I'm a mini collapsible</h3>
            <p>This is good for tight spaces.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>I'm another mini</h3>
            <p>Here's some collapsible content.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Last one</h3>
            <p>Final bit of collapsible content.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example! But it still doesn't work in my computer... http://prntscr.com/50rhgp

Comment: Hmmm ... well ... your screen shot sure does look like it is "normal" sized and not "mini".  We seem to have a mystery.  I am guessing it looks "mini" in the jsFiddle that I posted.  I guess our next step will be to look in great detail and your own HTML, JavaScript and CSS.  Can you post the files you are using somewhere we can look at them?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too for a long time in my app. Having thought about a lot I figured out that there is a conflict in linking style sheet. data-mini true works if you disabled the theme what I mean is just do not link themes style in your header and see the result. Hope it works. Thanks